# Regular expressions for parsing "abc.q=dfd" strings

Tags: php

I have string as `abvd.qweqw.sdfs.a=aqwrwewrwerrew`. I need to parse this string and get piece before `=` and after `=`. Symbol `.` can occur many times. So, please, tell me, which regular expression can I use for parsing? Thank you.

Comment: If you want code, ask for code; if you're asking for the expression, it's likely you will get just that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely based on your example:

```
/([a-z.]+)=([a-z]+)/
```

**Edit**

But actually:

```
/([a-z_.]+)=(.*)/i
```

The results are in memory groups 1 and 2. In code:

```
if (preg_match('/^([a-z_.]+)=(.*)/i', $str, $matches)) {
    // $matches[1] contains part before =
    // $matches[2] contains part after =
}
```

Btw, I've tweaked the expression by anchoring it (using `^`). If that doesn't work, just remove it from the expression.

Comment: Please, give me full PHP construction for it.

Comment: Thank you. And last question - If I give "112321312" string for it, what this expression returns?

Comment: @user1445877 when you have that string, `preg_match` will return `false` and the code inside the `if` condition will not get executed.

Comment: Oh, sorry, can you modify expression that before = can be used only a-z, A-Z and "_", and after = can be used any symbol?

Comment: @user1445877 define "any symbol" ... any symbol until the end of the string?

Comment: And THE LAST question - please, modify the example that string after "=" may be empty

Comment: No, for string "ProductDetails.next_product_text=" it results FALSE

Comment: @user1445877 it doesn't, please make sure you didn't make a mistake when copy-pasting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple string function for that.

```
list($first, $second) = explode('=', 'abvd.qweqw.sdfs.a=aqwrwewrwerrew);
```

Comment: @user1445877 That's too bad since regex would need the `=` as the separator too.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the full code.

```
<?php
   if(preg_match('/([a-z.]+)=([a-z]+)/', "abvd.qweqw.sdfs.a=aqwrwewrwerrew", $matches)){
      print $matches[1]."\n";
      print $matches[2]."\n";
   }
?>
```